# IT hit webdav Open non office files

Tags: file, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We are using IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library for our project to read and edit documents.

We have an issue on opening non-office files like pdf, txt.

When we try to open the file, the java applet (ajaxfilebrowser) is used to open the file. It shows a messagebox to allow the browser to run the exe and then the file is not opened. Instead My Documents folder is opened from the desktop.

Please advise how can we open the file?

Comment: Could you please post the URL of the file that fails to open. I thing Java applet may be unable to parse the Url for some reason.

Comment: Capturing request using Fiddler tool (or any other debugging proxy) could give the idea of what may be wrong. Could you post it here?

Comment: Thanks IT Hit team, I'll check the logs and the url and will update the query. Also, can the jar file be downloaded locally and used? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I had the same problem with a non-root site. That is, it would work well if the site was located directly at http://example.com, but not if it was located at http://example.com/mysite.

I think it had to do with the Java applet sending a bunch of special HTTP requests (PROP or something) to all ancestors of the WebDAV document. For the document http://example.com/mysite/dav/doc.pdf, this means http://example.com, http://example.com/mysite, http://example.com/mysite/dav, and finally http://example.com/mysite/dav/doc.pdf. In my case, the server was set up to respond appropriately to requests sent to http://example.com/mysite, but since the requests to http://example.com failed with some non-appropriate error code, it did not work.

Older versions of Microsoft Office had the same problem as the Java applet. From 2013 onwards, Office requests only the document in question (and possibly its immediate parent). Before that, it followed the same procedure as the Java applet, sending request to all ancestors of the document.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this issue is path being too long. This could be either a client side issue or a server side.

- In case of a server side, if you are running your server on .NET, please find the detailed description of the
  problem with some suggestions here:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx
- For a client side the only solution would be only making a path
  shorter.